# System.Net.WebRequest - Timeout error

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httpwebrequest, webrequest

The below piece of code is giving 
**Error Message : "The operation has timed out"
Error Sourse : at System.Net.httpWebRequest.GetResponse()**

This method is calling a URL and fetching the response object.

NOTE : This is all working fine in my end..but when i send the same code to production..it shows time oout errors

```
public GetUpdatedInventoryUnitValues(Vehicle aeVehicle)
{
            WebRequest oWebRequest = null;
            StringBuilder oStringBuilder = null;
            StreamReader oStreamReader = null;
            dcDealerDetails = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            MSRP = string.Empty;
            NetPrice = string.Empty;
            string strLine = string.Empty;
            string strURL = GetUpdatedInventoryUnitValues.GetFormattedURL(aeVehicle);

            try
            {
                /* Open the requested URL */
                oWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL);
                oWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                oWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
                /* Get the stream from the returned web response */
                oStreamReader = new StreamReader(oWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                /* Get the stream from the returned web response */
                oStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                /* Read the stream a line at a time and place each one into the stringbuilder  */
                while ((strLine = oStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    /* Ignore blank lines */
                    if (strLine.Length > 0)
                        oStringBuilder.Append(strLine);
                }

                string[] tempArray = null;
                string[] tempNextArray = null;
                //Split string by semicolon as a separater
                tempArray = Data.SplitString(oStringBuilder.ToString(), new char[] { ';' });

                if (tempArray != null)
                {
                    foreach (string invUnits in tempArray)
                    {
                        //Split string by '=' as a separater
                        tempNextArray = Data.SplitString(invUnits, new char[] { '=' });

                        if (tempNextArray != null && tempNextArray.Length == 2)
                        {
                            switch (tempNextArray[0].ToLower())
                            {
                                //case "msrp":
                                //    MSRP = Data.RemoveDoubleCode(tempNextArray[1]);
                                //    break;
                                case "netprice":
                                    NetPrice = Data.RemoveDoubleCode(tempNextArray[1]);
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLog.ErrorMessage = ErrorLog.Separator;
                ErrorLog.ErrorMessage = "Exception during posting data to another application .";
                ErrorLog.ErrorMessage = "ERROR MESSAGE : " + ex.Message;
                ErrorLog.ErrorMessage = "ERROR SOURCE: " + ex.StackTrace.ToString();

            }
            finally
            {
                if (oStreamReader != null)
                {
                    oStreamReader.Close();
                }
                if (oWebRequest != null)
                {
                    oWebRequest = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please suggest what am i doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Are you sure your request is good and it doesn't timeout out of the code? I mean have you tried to launch it directly in your browser?

Comment: It is all working fine in my end..but when i send the same code to production..it shows time oout errors

Comment: What are the differences between your developpement platform and your production platform? Is there any firewall or something like that which could stop your request?

Comment: Not sure if firewall is stopping production site..seems to be a potential cause in that case..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you perhaps finding that the first couple of requests are okay, and *then* they start timing out? If so, I suspect this is the problem:

```
oStreamReader = new StreamReader(oWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

You're fetching the response, but never disposing of it. You should use:

```
using (var response = oWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    ...
}
```

In fact, you can get rid of your `finally` block entirely if you use `using` statements throughout.

As an aside, this is a pretty long method - 77 lines! - and worse, it looks like it's actually a constructor:

- Try to split it out into smaller, more easily understood, more easily testable chunks
- Try to avoid doing a lot of work in constructors

Comment: ..This is working fine with my 250 calls in loop..but in production its almost all are timeouts..On code part..yes i should be doing it..

Comment: @RatanSharma: What URL are you fetching from production? Is it possible that it really is just timing out?

Comment: The above function is from the tool..which is running in production site...the function is calling a URL which is giving some response..This is working fine when i run the tool in my system , but in production server when i am running the same it is timming out..

Comment: About the URL where i am posting and getting the response also working without any issues.

Comment: @RatanSharma: You're getting the response from your system - but if you fetch it from your production system (e.g. on a browser), what happens?

Comment: oWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL); ..Here strURL is a third party url..When hit on a browser..is working fine..and giving me the needed response..

Comment: @RatanSharma: You should use something like Wireshark to look at the traffic on your prod network to find out what's going on. There's not a lot we can do, really.

Comment: After more than a year, you saved me once again without you even knowing it, thank you a lot @JonSkeet I just added the using statement you suggested and it's know working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing experience.

I was getting the same error "Operation Timed Out".

I have tried using both WebClient And WebRequest (set Timeout also) but was still getting error.

Reason was that I was not disposing the response.

So I used as mentioned above :

```
using (var response = oWebRequest.GetResponse())

{
    ...
}
```

And it solved the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I personnally use this code for one of my program and it works perfect:

```
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
    webRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
    WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream response = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response);
```

So i think it doesn't come from your code but from your production platform.

Comment: If you're not disposing of responses then it's not working perfectly - you're just getting lucky.

Comment: By using your posted code after the end of the using it disposes of the response?

Comment: Yes. You should use `using` statements for pretty much anything which implements `IDisposable`, to ensure clean-up.